# Prevent loop unrolling in shader program when using ANGLE

Tags: glsl, directx, hlsl, angle, webgl2

in my WEBGL shader I am using loop of unknown length (on compile).

```
    do {
        sample = texture(uTex, posXY).a;
        accumulated += aSample * uAMultiplier;
    } while (accumulated < 0.8);
```

This works as expected on OpenGL browsers, but by default windows chrome/ff uses angle, that unrolls loops, which isn't possible in this case, causing compile errors.

> Error: Error compiling generate
> Error: Cannot link program
> Info log:
> C:\fakepath(110,28-106): error X4014: cannot have gradient operations inside loops with divergent flow control
>
> C:\fakepath(59,12-96): warning X3570: gradient instruction used in a loop with varying iteration, forcing loop to unroll
> C:\fakepath(118,1-82): error X3511: unable to unroll loop, loop does not appear to terminate in a timely manner (1024 iterations)

Is there a solution to prevent unrolling or otherwise bypass having to loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to declare a static loop with an exit. For example

```
float accumulated = 0.0;
#define ITERATION_LIMIT 100;
for (int i = 0; i < ITERATION_LIMIT; ++i) {
  sample = texture(uTex, posXY).a;
  accumulated += aSample * uAMultiplier;
  if (accumulated >= 0.8) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Of course it's best to pick a reasonable number for the limit

Comment: I tried  `#pragma optionNV (unroll 1)` Doesn't seem to work. I could go debug HLSL, that is obtainable from context, but I found some more errors, caused by angle in other parts of application. So I gave up on angle. Do you know if it's possible to force OpenGl without user having to restart browser to opengl mode? This such a dogshit design. My chrome runs worse with opengl mode, but to run webgl, without errors, I can't rely on angle

Comment: `#pragma` is not part of WebGL. Forcing OpenGL will not fix your issue. The issue is not with ANGLE. The issue is WebGL disallows what you're trying to do.

Comment: Added a possible solution. see answer at bottom

Comment: pragma is part of webgl or GLSL and can be used to adjust HLSL with optionNV - I think it might be just for nvidia, but it still doesn't work for me.  What you posted is OpenGL 2.0 specs, I am using 3.0 without issues and has support for do-while loops without determined limit. WebGL clearly allows it and it stops at Angle translation. It goes as far that even If I adjust it to compile, it crashes my GPU driver!! I appreciate solution you posted, but it won't work in my case for multiple specific reasons. Only way to fix is to use OpenGl over Angle

Comment: Are you using WebGL or WebGL2? You tagged your question as WebGL not WebGL2. As for device specific pragmas both WebGL1 and WebGL2 disallows them. ANGLE is used in all versions of WebGL regardless of whether DirectX is under the hood or OpenGL. It's used as validation to make sure you aren't trying to use GL features that aren't part of WebGL and to make sure your shaders aren't going beyond the WebGL specs in terms of limits

Comment: oh yeah I am using WebGL2, my bad